# Gunzip .gz file in perl

Tags: perl, gunzip

I am working on Perl. and I need to download a .gz file from website, then  gunzip or decompress it in Perl. My code:

```
use LWP::Simple;
use XML::Simple qw(:strict);
use Data::Dumper;
use DBI;
use Getopt::Long;
use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw($GunzipError);
use IO::File;



my $url = 'http://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cve/nvdcve-2.0-Modified.xml.gz';

my $file = 'nvdcve-2.0-Modified.xml.gz';

getstore($url, $file);

my $xmlFile = 'nvdcve-2.0-Modified.xml';

gunzip $file => $xmlFile
    or die "gunzip failed: $GunzipError\n";
```

I use the Uncompress to release the file. The file downloaded and stored in $file successful, but the gunzip code is not working. Appreciate for any help, thanks.

Comment: Missing `use LWP::Simple`

Comment: @ssr1012 Hi I used, I just didn't copy that line, thank you.

Comment: Does it `die` with _gunzip failed:_? What's in `$GunzipError`?

Comment: I wonder why you think that posting a question here is easier than just [reading the module's documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Uncompress::Gunzip).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must import the `gunzip` function into your namespace:

```
use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw(gunzip $GunzipError);
```